# What happens if I Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() after an insert fails (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

The MSDN docs weren't entirely clear on this one. or perhaps I'm not reading them well enough.

If I do an insert (which may insert zero rows), followed by

```
;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And then call the command by ExecuteScalar()...

What will the result be if the Insert doesn't insert any rows?

I want to stop if it fails so that I don't continue on inserting child records to a bad, or wrong parent ID.

Comment: Don't forget about the parallel execution bug that exists in SQL Server for SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2019779

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If no Identity is inserted SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return null, you can check for the condition you specify by assigning SCOPE_IDENTITY() to a variable and then checking the variables contents.

Illustration

```
Create Proc SomeInsertToFail(@ID int OUTPUT)
as
Begin
    Select @ID =  Scope_Identity()
End
Declare @SOMEID int
Exec SomeInsertToFail @SOMEID OUTPUT
Select @SOMEID  --This will yield null
```

Comment: so can I do SELECT IsNull(Scope_Identity(), -1) so that I always get a valid INT and the fail value cant be an actual ID? (assuming of course my identity starts at 1)

Comment: might be worth testing on some more esoteric scenarios...  INSERT on a table where a trigger maintains integrity and raises an error to prevent the insert...

Comment: @Dems, thats a interesting test, I will give it a try.

Comment: Your example is technically correct but if there were other inserts in scope even if not the same table the select scope_identity() will return the id of the last successful insert.

Answer (score 5):

It depends upon whether there has been a SUCCESSFUL insert within the current scope.

```
declare @tb table (i int identity, ky varchar(100));

insert into @tb values('Success');

insert into @tb select ky from @tb where ky = 'Failure';

select SCOPE_IDENTITY();  -- returns 1
select * from @tb
```

Answer (score 4):

NULL

source: did a SELECT scope_identity() on a blank query (aka no insert)